# Loop through files in R and select rows by string

Tags: r, loops, read.csv

I have a large number of CSV files. I need to extract relevant data from each file, and compile all of the relevant data into a new file.

I have been copying/pasting the code below and changing relevant details (e.g., file name) to repeat the same process for many CSV files. After that, I use `cbind()`/`write.xlsx()` to combine all of the relevant data and write it to an excel file. I need a more efficient method to accomplish this task.

How can I:

1. incorporate a loop that imports a large number of CSV files (to replace #1 below)
2. select relevant rows based on a string instead of entering specific row numbers
   (to replace # 2 below)
3. combine all of the relevant data into a single data frame with each file's data in one column

```
library(tidyr)

# 1 - import raw data files 

file1 <- read.csv ("1.csv", header = FALSE, sep = "\n")

# 2 - select relevant rows

file1 <- as.data.frame(file1[c(41:155),])

colnames(file1) <- c("file1")

#separate components of each line from raw csv file / isolate data

temp1 <- separate(file1, file1, into = c("Text", "IntNum", "Data", sep = "\\s"))

temp1 <- temp1$Data

temp1 <- as.data.frame(temp1)
```

Comment: What do you mean with "select relevant rows based on a string"? Select rows which have a certain string in a specifc column? Is it the same string and column for each file (just different rows per file)?

Comment: Yes, I want to select the start and end rows in a specific column based on a string (e.g., "Target" and "Alt"). All data files are a single column. And yes, the string will be the same for all data files.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of relevant rows in each file is the same, you could do it like this. Option 1 shows a solution using a loop, option 2 shows a solution using `sapply`.

In a first step I generate three csv-files to make the code reproducible. The start row in each file is defined by "start", the end row by "end". I then get a list with the names of these files with `dir()`.

```
#make csv-files, target vector always same length (3)
set.seed(1)
for (i in 1:3) {
  df <- data.frame(x = c(rep(0, sample(1:10,1)), "begin", 
                         paste0("dat", i), 
                         "end",rep(0, sample(1:10, 1))))
  write.csv(df, file = paste0("file", i, ".csv"), quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
}

#get list of file names
allFiles <- dir(pattern = glob2rx("*.csv"))
```

**Option 1 - loop**
For the loop you could first initialize a result data frame ("outDF") with the number of columns set to the number of csv-files and the number of rows set to the length of the target vector in each file ("start" to "end"). You can then loop over the files and fill the data frame. The start and end rows can be indexed using `which()`.

```
#initialise result data frame
outDF <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 3, ncol = length(allFiles),
                         dimnames = list(NULL, allFiles)))

#loop over csv files
for (iFile in allFiles) {
  idat <- read.csv(iFile, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) #read csv
  outDF[, iFile] <- idat[which(idat$x == "start"):which(idat$x == "end"),]
}
```

**Option 2 - sapply**
Instead of a loop you could use `sapply` with a custom function to extract the relevant rows in each file. This returns a matrix which you could then transform into a dataframe.

```
out <- sapply(allFiles, FUN = function(x) {
  idat <- read.csv(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  return(idat[which(idat$x == "start"):which(idat$x == "end"),])
})

outDF <- as.data.frame(out)
```

If the number of rows between "start" and "end" differs between files, the above options won´t work. In this case you could generate a data frame by first using `lapply()` (similar to option 2) to generate a result list (with different lengths of the list elements) and then padding shorter lists with NAs before transforming the result into a dataframe again.

```
#make csv-files with with target vector of different lengths (3:12)
set.seed(1)
for (i in 1:3) {
  df <- data.frame(x = c(rep(0, sample(1:10,1)), "start", 
                         rep(paste0("dat", i), sample(1:10,1)), 
                         "end",rep(0, sample(1:10, 1))))
  write.csv(df, file = paste0("file", i, ".csv"), quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
}

#lapply
out <- lapply(allFiles, FUN = function(x) {
  idat = read.csv(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  return(idat[which(idat$x == "start"):which(idat$x == "end"),])
})

out <- lapply(out, `length<-`, max(lengths(out)))
outDF <- do.call(cbind, out)
```